# Replace if last value of group is missing with a POSIXct variable

Tags: datetime, replace, group-by, dplyr

I would like to replace the last value of the enddt variable to the value "2019-03-31 23:59:59" if it is missing.

```
ID  stdt                enddt               goal 
1   11/21/2018 7:11     12/31/2018 23:59    12/31/2018 23:59
1   1/21/2019 0:00      1/22/2019 5:19      1/22/2019 5:19
1   1/22/2018 5:19                          3/31/2019 23:59
2   12/17/2018 16:49    3/31/2018 21:59     3/31/2018 21:59
2   3/31/2018 22:00     12/21/2018 23:05    12/21/2018 23:05
2   12/21/2018 23:05    1/16/2019 8:32      1/16/2019 8:32
```

My attempt didn't work. It generates a single value for each id (first enddt value).

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(goal= ifelse(is.null(last(enddt)), "2019-03-31 23:59:59", enddt)) %>%
  ungroup()

hh3$goal<- as.POSIXct(hh3$goal, origin = "1960-01-01")
```

My date/time variable are a "POSIXct" "POSIXt" class. Perhaps I need to change the class of this variable using chron??

Thank you in advance.
Marvin

Answer (score 0):

There are two funky things you are running up against.

1. `ifelse()` on a date often has unexpected outputs. Because `enddt` has a POSIXct class, the new result of `goal` should have it as well.
2. in the `ifelse()` statement, you are asking if 1 thing is TRUE and then to go row-by-row and generate an output. This too can create unexpected warnings and outputs. A way around this is to create a helper column as I did below (`missing_date`). The other way to fix this is something like this `ifelse(rep(is.na(last(enddt)), n()), as.POSIXct("2019-03-31 23:59:59"), enddt)` but I think the helper column is easier to follow.

See if this helps you along

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate) #mdy_hm function

df <- data.table::fread(
  "ID   stdt    enddt   goal
  1 11/21/2018 7:11 3/31/2019 23:59 3/31/2019 23:59
  1 11/21/2018 7:11 11/22/2018 5:19 11/22/2018 5:19
  1 11/22/2018 5:19     3/31/2018 23:59
  2 12/17/2018 16:49    3/31/2019 23:59 3/31/2019 23:59
  2 12/17/2018 16:49    12/21/2018 23:05    12/21/2018 23:05
  2 12/21/2018 23:05    1/16/2019 8:32  1/16/2019 8:32"
  ) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(c(ends_with("dt"), "goal")), mdy_hm)


df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(
    # this puts a T/F in every column, note, is.na vs is.null
    missing_date = is.na(last(enddt)),
    goal = ifelse(missing_date, as.POSIXct("2019-03-31 23:59:59"), enddt)
  ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  # 1970 instead of 1960
  mutate(goal = as.POSIXct(goal, origin = "1970-01-01")) %>% 
  # remove this column
  select(-missing_date)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for replying; I appreciate it. But the code didn't work since it assigns the new value (3/31/2019 23:59) to all rows of my group instead of only assigning it to the row with missing value. I changed and sorted my data example so it is easier to understand. To recap, I just to to assign the new date to the missing cells.

Comment: In that case you can just use the 2 lines with `mutate (goal ...)`

Comment: The problem is that I only need to replace last observation of a group. If it is missing in other places I don't want to replace it. I will look more into this and perhaps change my post to give a better sense of this task. Thanks!

Comment: I think you can change this line `missing_date = (is.na(enddt) & enddt == last(enddt))`